# "pygame.error: display Surface quit" when running the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to make a simple moving game with Pygame since I am currently learning it. Whenever i try to run the code I keep on getting a problem saying: "pygame.error: display Surface quit"

I've tried adding "break" at the end but the window closes immediately! I've tried searching for the solution but I can't find one that helps my code.

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
# Window setup
size = [400, 400]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# player position
x = size[0] // 2
y = size[1] // 2

# ball position
ballX = random.randrange(0, size[0])
ballY = random.randrange(0, size[1])

# colours
red = pygame.color.Color('#FF8080')
blue = pygame.color.Color('#8080FF')
white = pygame.color.Color('#FFFFFF')
black = pygame.color.Color('#000000')


def CheckOffScreenX(x):
    if x > size[0]:
        x = 0
    elif x < 0:
        x = size[0]
    return x
def CheckOffScreenY(y):
    if y > size[1]:
        y = 0
    elif y < 0:
        y = size[1]
    return y

# Game loop
done = False
while not done:
    screen.fill(black)


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    #player movement
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y -=1
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y +=1
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -=1
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x +=1

    # Check offscreen
    x = CheckOffScreenX(x)
    y = CheckOffScreenY(y)

    # draw player
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, [x, y], 6)
    pygame.display.flip()

    # draw ball
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, blue, [ballX, ballY], 6)
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    clock.tick(32)
    pygame.quit()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) insider the main loop. `pygame.quit()` uninitialize all pygame modules. After the modules are uninitialized all further calls to pygyme instructions (in the next frame) will cause a crash.
Do `pygame.quit()` after the main loop, when the application has end.

```py
done = False
while not done:
    screen.fill(black)

    # [...]

    # pygame.quit() <----- delete

pygame.quit() # <---- add
```

Note, probably you've added an [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) when you copied the code.

Comment: ah thank you very much!! I was learning Python from a book and I am starting to think that the book was mainly for Python 2!

Comment: @AzaamHoldman Thank you. You're welcome. Note, that is not different in Python 2.